# Генерация хэша для восстановления пароля пользователя PHP

Tags: php, хеширование

Задался вопросом как сделать восстановление пароля пользователя, **но без использования базы данных** для хранения сгенерированного хэша для ссылки восстановления пароля. **Хранить хэш каким-то другим способом тоже нельзя**.

Из базовых условий:

1. Ссылка действительная только для текущего email и пароля пользователя(точнее для хэша пароля, т.к. в базе хранится только он)
2. Ссылка действительная только в течение 24 часов после создания

Если бы не было второго пункта, то можно было бы просто генерировать каким-то образом хэш от текущего mail и пароля пользователя + добавлять какие-то секретные символы со стороны сервера, а потом сверять какой хэш дал пользователь.

Но как быть со вторым пунктом? Если подставить в хэш ещё метку времени, то не получится.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нашёл выход сам.

Решение №1.
Не самое удачное, если срок действия ссылки более суток.

```
$email      = 'email@mail.ru';
$hashPass   = 'текущий_хэш_пароля_из_бд';

//хэш, который будет отправлен пользователю вместе с ссылкой
$hash       = md5($email.$hashPass.time());

echo "http://mysite.ru/restore?hash=".$hash.'<br>';

//так будет выглядеть проверка корректности хэша
$time       = time();
for ($i = 0; $i <= 86400; $i++){
    if ($hash === md5($email.$hashPass.($time - $i))){
        echo 'Хэш совпадает!';
        break;
    }
}
```

Решение №2. С симметричным шифрованием.

```
function base64_url_encode($input) {
    return strtr(base64_encode($input), '+/=', '-_,');
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
    return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_,', '+/='));
}

function my_encode($data,$key,$iv){
    $enc = $data.openssl_encrypt(time(), "AES-128-CBC", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    return base64_url_encode($enc);
}

function my_decode($data,$key,$iv){
    $enc = openssl_decrypt($data, "AES-128-CBC", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    return $enc;
}

$appCodeKey = '16CodeKeySymbols'; //Initialization Vector для openssl_encrypt/openssl_decrypt
$email      = 'email@mail.ru';
$hashPass   = 'текущий_хэш_пароля_из_бд';
//md5 для примера, можно изменить на другие более криптостойкие алгоритмы
$key        = md5($email); 
$hash       = md5($email.$hashPass);

$encode     = my_encode($hash,$key,$appCodeKey);    

echo "http://mysite.ru/restore?hash=".$encode.'<br>';

//проверка корректности хэша
$decode     = base64_url_decode($encode,$key,$appCodeKey);

$dec_hash   = substr($decode,0,32);
$dec_time   = my_decode(substr($decode,32),$key,$appCodeKey);

if ($dec_hash === $hash && $dec_time >= time() - 86400){
    echo 'Корректный хэш';
}
```

Наверняка, можно проще или что-то изменить, необязательно хэшировать во втором варианте или передавать email в открытом виде, вторым параметром.

Решение №3.

```
$ts = strtotime("+1 day");
$link = "http://mysite.ru/restore?email=".urlencode($email)."&ts=$ts&hash=".md5($pass_hash.$email.$ts);
```

**Суть задачи была в теории, а не в практической составляющей.**
Это будет работать. Вот чего я хотел добиться.

Answer (score 1):

Я считаю , что никак.
Обьясню почему: 
1) все статические источники храненения данных, такие как запись хешей в файл - можно считать некой базой, тут шило на мыло.
2) Возможно вам подойдет вариант  записывать в сессию, что не безопасно во-первых, и не практично во-вторых. Т.к пользователь может сделать запрос с одного компьютера, а перейти по ссылке с другого.   Но если это типа задачки с универа, то можно реализовать так, и как раз решится проблема с оут тайм , просто храненить сессию будите 24 часа

И если вам не сложно, обьясните , для чего этот велосипед вам нужен?

дополнения ( после комента автора )

пришел в голову один безбожный костыль
он будет работать при условии, что пользователь востанавливает пароль , и не заходит в систему ( т.к можно знать текущий пароль, и просто нажать востанавить )

Хешировать всю строку в базе + поле начала процесса востанавления пароля ( мы же не хеш храним )

После, при переходе по ссылке, мы поочередно хешируем все строки в базе и сравниваем каждую с хешем который прилетел в урле ( если пользователь не заходил в систему , то строка в базе не изменилась, тоесть хеш будет одинаковым ) , находим совпедению, смотрим в базе метку начала востанвления, сравниваем с текущей датой ( 24 часа действия ссылки ) ну и делаем что то если меньше 24 часов прошло...

Вот такая логика

Comment: Вопрос не в практической составляющей. Вопрос задали на собеседовании, я не нашёл решения. Но в итоге не сказали как можно было это реализовать, хотя утверждали уверенно, что решение есть, вот теперь мне интересно как. Хранить хэш вообще нигде нельзя, не в базе, не в файле, не в сессии. Мы можем использовать только те данные, что уже есть в базе. Ну и нужно выполнить 2 условия описанных в посте.

Comment: В том то и проблема. Что нельзя сохранять метку начала восстановления тоже. Всё что у нас есть - текущий пароль пользователя(или хэш в бд, не важно), текущий почтовый адрес пользователя. Мы отправляем пользователю ссылку, которая действительная 24 часа и должны проверить действительно ли это он и действительна ли ссылка(параметры её). Должно быть хэширование, а не шифрование.

Comment: хорошо, тогда в ссылке делать дополнительный гет параметр с временем

Answer (score 0):

Берем структуру данных содержащую:

```
1. email
2. TTL
3. Новый пароль
```

Шифруем все это - получаем хеш, отдаем хеш пользователю

При получении хеша - расшифровываем, проверяем TTL и наличие email, меняем пароль

Comment: Задача не подразумевает расшифровку пришедшего хзша от пользователя. Его нужно только сверить со своим(md5, sha и др. подобные алгоритмы), а не расшифровывать. Да и думаю это очень небезопасно.

Comment: Хотя мне решение от более опытного пользователя , очень нравится!